# Hyperledger Test Network Bring Up Stuck

Tags: testing, networking, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[hyperledger-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq25L.png)
I am using the command below to setup a test network on a Windows with a Docker Image setup and getting stuck at this part of the setup. I have multiple hyperledger docker images but am currently running hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest

```
./network.sh up
```

Does anyone know if the reason for getting stuck & how I can bypass it?

I attempted using the command below to shutdown previous networks

```
./network.sh down
```

I had an error with Docker, because I was not running it but I do not have a Docker error now, I'm just stuck at the setup

The output log is below & get's stuck on creating peer orgs:

```
Using docker and docker-compose
Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds 
and using database 'leveldb'
LOCAL_VERSION=v2.5.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=v2.5.0
Network fabric_test  Creating
Network fabric_test  Created
Volume "compose_peer0.org2.example.com"  Creating
Volume "compose_peer0.org2.example.com"  Created
Volume "compose_orderer.example.com"  Creating
Volume "compose_orderer.example.com"  Created
Volume "compose_peer0.org1.example.com"  Creating
Volume "compose_peer0.org1.example.com"  Created
Container peer0.org2.example.com  Creating
Container peer0.org1.example.com  Creating
Container orderer.example.com  Creating
```

Comment: Hi there, can you please share your full logs, particularly last lines

Comment: don't you get anything else besides this?

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov no the log stops there

Comment: when you type `docker ps` what running containers can you see?

Comment: CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
5d7cc27bc7e5   hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest   "fabric-ca-server st…"   12 days ago   Up 4 seconds   7054/tcp   cranky_neumann

Comment: Please put that information to your post , so that your question becomes more clear. Now you are missing too many things

Comment: @shallowBender Could you please help me with this problem too? As far as I see, you're trying to run HyperLedger Fabric, and so do I. I have the same problem like you did a year ago and I think it would be great if you shared it with me on how it's solved?

Comment: @MarkVirchenko I deleted the containers, uninstalled Docker, then reinstalled Docker, I forgot if I did additional configuration but my Docker instance was the problem